# Approximation Distributions

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, poisson-distribution, binomial-distribution

Can someone explain why in distributions:

1. $ \operatorname{Binomial}(n,p)\approx  \operatorname{Normal}(np, np(1-p))$
2. $ \operatorname{Binomial}(n,p) \approx  \operatorname{Poisson}(np)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It's the result of the Central limit Theorem in the version of [De Moivre - Laplace](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%E2%80%93Laplace_theorem)
2. It's the limit distribution of a binomial when $p=\lambda/n$